# Xpath how to located div into another div?

Tags: xpath, odoo-8, openerp-8

I'm new with odoo and xpath. After googling and reading all similar question in stack. I can't find solution to my problem:

How to located div into another div using xpath ?

Below all my failed attempt to reach my aim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <!-- Customize header  -->
    <template id="custom_header" inherit_id="website.layout" name="Custom Header">
       <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/main/div[1]" position="attributes">
           <attribute name="id">my_target</attribute>
       </xpath>

      <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_structure oe_empty']" position="attributes">
           <attribute name="id">my_target</attribute>
      </xpath>

      <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/main/following-sibling::div[1]/data()" position="attributes">
           <attribute name="id">my_target</attribute>
      </xpath>

      <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/main/following-sibling::div[1]" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="id">my_target</attribute>
      </xpath>

  </template>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

I have got error:

Element '....' cannot be located in parent view.

However, I'm using the following expression in another task and it works very well:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <!-- Customize header  -->
    <template id="custom_header" inherit_id="website.layout" name="Custom Header">
      <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/header" position="attributes">
         <attribute name="id">my_header</attribute>
      </xpath>
    </template>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

Below the structure taken from chrome inspector:

[image]

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Do you have `xmlns="..."` anywhere in the input? Hard to tell from the screenshot.

Comment: Just click into image to display it in full screen. or do you want to publish an xml code instead of screenshot !!?

Comment: I looked at it in full screen and it looks like the `html` tag is cut off. Actual data is helpful. Hard to copy/paste a screenshot and actually try to run xpaths on it.

Comment: Just to let you know, with Chrome Debugger you can right click on the node and go to Copy -> Copy XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few valid examples:

These are for locating the div with the id wrap:

```
//div[@id='wrapwrap']//div[@id='wrap']
//main/div[@id='wrap']
//div[@id='wrap']
```

For locating the div from this div that has the class 'container oe_website_sale' replace the 
    @id='wrap'
with
    @class='container oe_website_sale'

There are based on the id, you can also replace the id with the class and class value.

Comment: Sorry, but no one of examples above work for me !! Always the same error " Element can not be located" ... !!

Comment: If it works manually you might have a coding issue or maybe the element is not found because the page is not loaded or you are not on the right page. I checked all the variants manually and all of them are working.

Comment: I edited my question to show you the template where I called my xpath expression.

Comment: This worked for me      <xpath expr="//div[@id='informations']" position="inside"></xpath>

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I would like to point out for you is that in XML templates you are modifying not the complete view that is visible in the Developer tools of a browser, but the *parent XML template itself*.

In this case, you are modifying `website.layout` indicated by the `inherit_id="website.layout"` attribute. You should open that template and try to modify the elements based on what it contains rather than the end result in browser.